# Laravel 10 validation - Min and max values for numeric inputs

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-10

Reading the docs, there doesn't appear to be a way to validate the range of permissible values of numeric (non-integer) inputs. `min` and `max` validate the number of digits of the number, not the value. See my code:

```php
$request->validate([
  'ratio' => 'required|numeric|min:0.01|max:1'; // not limited to 2 decimals
]);
```

Submitting the form with `ratio=0.3333` fails:

> The ratio field must not be greater than 1 character.

Is there any way to do what I want with built-in Laravel validation rules, or do I have to write my own?

Comment: I have no issue with `numeric|min:0.01|max:1` working fine with the input of `'0.3333'` ...

Comment: this works perfectly fine for me ...  the `numeric` in the rule forces the rest of the rules to treat the input as a numeric, and when it is numeric the size rule uses the value, not number of characters (which would be for strings) ... the `size` rule is just a reference so other rules that evaluate values in a similar way don't have to explain the same thing over and over again

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, you need to validate this ratio between two values. So, I think this may be useful to you.

```
'ratio' => 'required|numeric|between:1,100';
```

Comment: "Strings, numerics, arrays, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule." I don't want the `size` rule. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-between

Comment: @jkoop "...evaluated in the same **fashion** as the size rule" .. the size rule isn't being used, it is just a reference to how different types are handled

Answer (score -2):

Oh bother. My question was wrong.

I simplified my code to as simple as I thought possible, but I'd over-simplified it.

My actual code was

```php
$request->validate([
  'ratio' => 'required|numeric',
]);
$request->validate([
  'ratio' => 'min:0.01|max:1',
]);
```

which, it turns out, *actually* doesn't work.

I added `numeric` the second rule, and then it worked.